# Continuous onto map to a space with cofinite topology.

Tags: general-topology

Can we have a continuous onto map from a space X to a cofinite space Y.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: The identity $f(x)=x$ is a quotient map (assuming both sides have the same topology).

Comment: @freakish If identity were a quotient map, $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R_{cf}$ would be homeomorphic, but are not. Edit: sorry, missed the remark about having the same topology - but OP isn't asking about that.

Comment: @freakish The OP says "respectively", which means that $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R_{cof}$.

Comment: Without specifying anything about $X$, there's no definite answer. For example, $X$ might simply not have enough elements for an onto-map to $Y$, continuous or not. On the other hand, $X$ might have the discrete topology, then every map from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous, including any onto map, provided one exists.

Comment: Any map from a set X onto a space Y can be made continuous - and a quotient - by choosing the topology on X formed by the inverse images of open sets of Y. Your original question is much more interesting. I suspect no-one has answered because no-one can see how to, not that no-one has tried. If you look at the top question in the related section there is speculation that the problem may even be independent of ZFC. (The answers there are misleading, they wrongly assume the map must be open.)